# How does one define default key=>value pair behavior on route params in Phalcon?

Tags: php, frameworks, url-routing, phalcon

I would like to define the following default behavior on my routes:

```
Url: myapp.com/mymodule/mycontroller/myaction/q/someTerm/key/someValue/key2/anotherValue
```

This url should give the dispatcher the following params:

```
array(
    'q' => 'someTerm',
    'key' => 'someValue',
    'key2' => 'anotherValue'
):
```

I know it can be easily done by extending the router and implementing my own, but I was wondering if Phalcon has a default flag that switches that approach on by default.

Right now, if I apply the route

':module/:controller/:action/:params' to this URL, I get the following params:

```
array(
    0 => 'q',
    1 => 'someTerm',
    2 => 'key'
    ... etc
);
```

Which is something I don't want.

If the Phalcon router doesn't have a default flag that does this, is there an event that fires immediately before the params become available in the DI's dispatcher in the controller? I would like to manually map them into key=>value pairs at least, before they reach the controller.

Edit: I am now looking into the beforeExecuteRoute event in the controller, should do what I need. But I'd still like it if the router did this automatically - sometimes params aren't in a fixed order, or some of them just disappear (think complex search queries).

Comment: I haven't researched this but in an application I wrote I just used the assumption of X variable being in Y position. i.e. in your example I did not use the /q/, /key/ etc. and the url was: myaction/someTerm/someValue/AnotherValue etc. Let me Ping @twistedxtra for more input on this.

Comment: Yes, it is essential that I can mix and match the variables - sometimes some of them will be missing, other times, their positions will simply the mixed. I now know about the event I can use to accomplish this, so I'm updating my original question, but I'd still like the router to do this on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can intercept the 'beforeDispatchLoop' event in the dispatcher to transform the parameters before dispatch the action:

```
$di['dispatcher'] = function(){

    $eventsManager = new Phalcon\Events\Manager();

    $eventsManager->attach('dispatch', function($event, $dispatcher) {
        if ($event->getType() == 'beforeDispatchLoop') {
            $keyParams = array();
            $params = $dispatcher->getParams();
            foreach ($params as $number => $value) {
                if ($number & 1) {
                    $keyParams[$params[$number - 1]] = $value;
                }
            }
            $dispatcher->setParams($keyParams);
        }
    });

    $dispatcher = new Phalcon\MVc\Dispatcher();
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

    return $dispatcher;
});
```

Then use the transformed parameters in the controller:

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

        print_r($this->dispatcher->getParams());
        print_r($this->dispatcher->getParam('key'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I initially made it work with a beforeExecuteRoute event in the base controller, but your solution is better as it leaves all configuration in the bootstrap.